# Paypal REST api "ORDER_NOT_APPROVED" after successfully going through checkout flow via react native webview

Tags: reactjs, react-native, rest, express, paypal

SOLUTION: Make sure you're not stuck in an infinite loop of redirects leading to no approval of the payment. Make sure you put a "return_url" such as the code snippet i used below... This solved my problem and i finally got an approval after nearly 7 hours of headaches.

```
             const dataString = `{
                "intent": "CAPTURE",
                "purchase_units": [{
                    "amount": {
                        "currency_code": "USD",
                        "value": "${amount.toFixed(2).toString()}"
                    },
                    "payee": {
                        "email_address": "${user.paypal_payment_address.toString()}"
                    },
                    "payment_instruction": {
                        "disbursement_mode": "DELAYED"
                    }
                }],
                "payer": {
                    "email_address": "${email.toLowerCase()}"
                },
                "application_context": {
                    "return_url": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders/9V25205876068781J/capture"
                }
            }`;
```

I'm using the MERN stack (mongodb, node, react native, express.JS - so just javascript) but I'm trying to do a "delayed" payment with the PayPal REST api. I successfully create the order with the following code...

```
mongo.connect(config.get("mongoURI"),  { useNewUrlParser: true }, { useUnifiedTopology: true }, cors(), (err, db) => {
router.post("/", (req, res) => {

    const { amount, vehicle, paypal_access_token } = req.body;
    
    const database = db.db("<dbname>");

    const collection = database.collection("users");

    collection.findOne({ "broken_vehicles_listings.id": vehicle.id }).then((user) => {
        if (user) {

            const configgg = {
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                    "Authorization": `Bearer ${paypal_access_token}`,
                    "PayPal-Partner-Attribution-Id": null
                }
            }

            const headers = {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': `Bearer ${paypal_access_token}`
            };
            
            const dataString = `{
                "intent": "CAPTURE",
                "purchase_units": [{
                    "amount": {
                        "currency_code": "USD",
                        "value": "${amount.toFixed(2).toString()}"
                    },
                    "payee": {
                        "email_address": "${user.paypal_payment_address.toString()}"
                    },
                    "payment_instruction": {
                        "disbursement_mode": "DELAYED"
                    }
                }]
            }`;
            
            const options = {
                url: 'https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders',
                method: 'POST',
                headers: headers,
                body: dataString
            };
            
            const callback = (error, response, body) => {
                if (!error) {
                    const parsed = JSON.parse(body);

                    console.log("MAJIC HAPPENED!!!!!!: ", parsed);

                    res.json({
                        message: "Successfully executed paypal logic!",
                        links: parsed.links,
                        data: parsed
                    })
                } else {
                    console.log(error);
                }
            }
            
            request(options, callback);

        } else {
            res.json({
                message: "Could not locate the appropriate user..."
            })
        }
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
    });
});
```

});

This successfully creates a paypal order but i need to get the order status to "APPROVED" which apparently isn't happening even though it redirects me "back to test store" after choosing and submitting the desired payment option. When i use the below code snippet to "CAPTURE" the order is get an error stating

"Payer has not yet approved the Order for payment. Please redirect the payer to the 'rel':'approve' url returned as part of the HATEOAS links within the Create Order call or provide a valid payment_source in the request."

I do exactly as it says and use the "approve" url in react native webview to process the interaction within my app instead of leaving the app. The package used is react-native-webview.

```
mongo.connect(config.get("mongoURI"),  { useNewUrlParser: true }, { useUnifiedTopology: true }, cors(), (err, db) => {
router.post("/", (req, res) => {

    const { id, paypal_access_token, order_id } = req.body;

    console.log("req.body", req.body);

    const headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${paypal_access_token}`
    };
    
    const dataString = `{}`;
    
    const options = {
        url: `https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders/${order_id}/authorize`,
        method: 'POST',
        headers: headers,
        body: dataString
    };
    
    const callback = (error, response, body) => {
        if (!error) {
            const parsed = JSON.parse(body);

            console.log("IT WORKED!!~!", parsed);
        } else {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }
    
    request(options, callback);
  });
});
```

I'm either doing something significantly wrong or paypal documentation sucks. please help.....

EDIT: I just confirmed the order is in "created" status but i cannot figure out how to get it into "approved" status

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution **100%**, the problem is that when a user accepts payment, need to navigate to a waiting page, then call the **CAPTURE** api to complete :

```
            "intent": "CAPTURE",
            "application_context":{
                "user_action":"PAY_NOW",
                "return_url":"https://example.com/",// Very important
                "cancel_url":"https://example.com/"
            },
            "purchase_units": [
              {
                "amount": {
                  "currency_code": "USD",
                  "value": "100.00"
                }
              }
            ],
```